# Need for Functions to be Increasing in Non-deterministic Time Hierarchy Theorem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was going over the proofs of the non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem (the one in Arora-Barak and the one by Fortnow and Santhanam). They are available here:

http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf : page 67

https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2011/04/new-proof-of-nondeterministic-time.html

It seems to me that we need $f$ and $g$ to be increasing functions, in addition to the usual assumptions that $f(n+1)=o(g(n))$ and time-constructibility.

In the Arora-Barak proof, we divide the natural numbers into disjoint intervals. I'm not sure how one can find, given a number $n$, which interval it lies in, without assuming that functions are increasing.
In the Fortnow-Santhanam proof, this is needed to ensure that $t_1(i+m+2)$ (which I believe may be a typo and should be in terms of $t_2$) can be computed in time $O(t_2(n))$.

Just for reference, I also posted this on cstheory stackexchange here:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48318/increasing-functions-in-non-deterministic-time-hierarchy-theorems

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Please pick one site where you want the question to remain open.

Comment: I don't see a question here, just a set of statements.  Do you have a specific question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to clearly articulate a specific question.